# Opengl Mesa : use opengl 4.0

Tags: opengl, mesa

I'm an opengl programmer, and I would like to use opengl 4.0; problem is that I cannot install any proprietary drivers, and when I type : glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version" in the terminal, it outputs me :

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
```

Can anyone tell me how I could update mesa to 4.x+ ?

EDit :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1972
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: ok, I'll do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL 4.0 is not supported in Linux for Intel graphics adapters yet.

4.1 should be supported by Mesa 11.0, that planned to be released in September 2015.

Comment: Ok.... and when wil the other version be supported ? like 4.4 ?

Comment: 4.1 is planned to be supported in mesa 11. Nobody knows when 4.4 will be.

Comment: Isn't there another way to program in opengl 4.4 ?

Comment: Buy an Nvidia card. 4.5 is already supported in linux. Probably AMD too.

Comment: I bought an NVidia gtx750 TI card : now it works fine :)