# Switch OpenGL loader to NVidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, opengl

***I am trying to compile OpenGL code on a machine with NVidia 4.18 graphics driver and CUDA 10.1 installed. It is currently not linking with OpenGL like  `-lGL` on the command line.***

I recently set up my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine with CUDA 10.1 from the local `runfile` installer. I said to install everything in the installer.
I can see by `nvidia-smi` that the `1050Ti` is detected properly without problems.
My issue is that I cannot run OpenGL programs.
Some programs (not made by me) compile, but then throw this error when I try to run them:

```
Unable to create OpenGL context.
```

This leads me to think that OpenGL is not installed properly.
I then checked to see what OpenGL version I am running right now.
I checked the version with the command:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

On my machine that is **NOT** working, I get this output:

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.0.8
```

On a separate machine that **DOES** work, I get this output from the same `glxinfo` command:

```
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 410.48
```

(notice I am using a different driver than on my broken machine. That should not matter since both are using CUDA 10.X, at least, that is my understanding)

So, I see that I need to switch from `Mesa` to `NVidia` OpenGL loaders.

So, seeing this information,

- How do I switch to the correct OpenGL loader?

I have consulted many links before creating this question.

- [How do I get OpenGL working on an Nvidia GeForce GT 750M?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389901/how-do-i-get-opengl-working-on-an-nvidia-geforce-gt-750m)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/bbc1kx/ubuntu_1804_nvidia_driver_wont_load
- [Opengl Mesa : use opengl 4.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652145/opengl-mesa-use-opengl-4-0)
- [How to emulate/replace OpenGL version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834274/how-to-emulate-replace-opengl-version)
- [How to check the information of current installed video drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28033/how-to-check-the-information-of-current-installed-video-drivers)
- [How can I find what video driver is in use on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system)
- [What is terminal command that can show OpenGL version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47062/what-is-terminal-command-that-can-show-opengl-version)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using Nvidia GT 630.

Applications like Any desk which depends on OpenGL will not work properly on Nvidia drivers.

[image: inxi output]

Based on [this question in Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864730/couldnt-find-rgb-glx-visual-or-fbconfig), it is needed to remove Nvidia and switch back to default Nouveau driver to get it fixed.